# Graphql is returing the error as "Can't parse `Array` value, expected array" when I'm trying to run gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client, hasura

I'm trying a mutation query in Android using ApolloClient below is my `.graphql` file

```
mutation insertAddress($city: String, $landmark: String, $postcode: Int, $state: String, $type: String, $userUuid: String) {
    __typename
    insert_addresses(objects: {city: $city, landmark: $landmark, postcode: $postcode, state: $state, type: $type, userUuid: $userUuid}) {
      returning {
          uuid
      }
   }
}
```

I'm getting the error as `` com.sample.app\InsertAddress.graphql (3:30) Can't parse `Array` value, expected array ``
Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try

```
    mutation insertAddress($city: String, $landmark: String, $postcode: Int, $state: String, $type: String, $userUuid: String) {
    __typename
    insert_addresses(objects: [{city: $city, landmark: $landmark, postcode: $postcode, state: $state, type: $type, userUuid: $userUuid}]) {
      returning {
          uuid
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/insert.html